# Wi-Fi doesn't work on Packard Bell Easynote A6

Tags: wireless

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit on a Packard Bell Easynote A6. Ubuntu in general works well, with the exception of the Wi-Fi. I have looked around on the internet a bit and I think that the problem has to do with the drivers for the wireless card, a Realtek RTL8139. I tried to use a tool that (supposedly) allows me to use Windows drivers on Linux, but it did not work.  How can I fix my problem?

Comment: Realtek 8139 is an ethernet card, not wireless. Please run the terminal command: lspci -nn and tell us the details of the wireless card.

Answer (score -1):

I had to install wireless firmware on an HP laptop I was working on a while back. It took care of the problem for me. Type this command in the terminal. If lack of firmware is your problem, this should take care of everything for you.

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Why do you think his wireless card is a Broadcom?